# How do I finely process/puree a large amount of chillies?

Tags: equipment, food-processing, chili-peppers, hot-sauce, puree

I have a large quantity of chillies that I would like to make a hot sauce out of. But firstly I would like to create a really fine puree out of these chillies, is anyone aware of the appropriate equipment that will allow me to do this? I don't think a conventional food processor will suffice as it will leave coarse bits of chilli. What are my options?

Comment: Pestle and mortar?

Comment: @Doug that's not practical, it's a large quantity

Comment: Vitamix or Blendtec? Are you peeling the chilis? You could use a French Sieve or a ricer?

Comment: @Catija I'm just destemming them. That's the thing, I want to puree them to the extent where near most of the whole chilli after it's been processed passes through a fine sieve. I don't think this is possible with a vitamix, I've tried it before and far too much chilli gets caught in the ricer/sieve at the end because it hasn't been processed finely enough. I want to maximise my yields from the chillies. Would this be possible with a hand blender?

Comment: Because of how tough the peels are, I have a difficult time imagining being able to grind them finely enough to not have a ton stuck in your sieve. The flesh is the part you want, just like with tomatoes... and that's why you sieve them... to get the peels (and seeds) out. I also feel that hand blenders (you mean an immersion blender?) will tend to be more spotty than something like a blendtec or vitamix.

Comment: With gloves, goggles, and a respirator. Seriously. No matter how careful you are you will wind up in a world of pain. This is personal experience talking.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you will be cooking the sauce. If this is the case, my recommendation is to cook the chillies first and puree them afterwards, as with traditional ljutenica or ajwar. In this case, you can either peel the skin off after charring it and then process the resulting soft flesh whichever way you want (it's very easy, leaves no chunks), or put them unskinned through a meat grinder with a special disk which separates the skins from the pureed flesh.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a food mill with the fine disc for this, personally.

It will prevent the skin (if sufficiently tough) from making it through to the final result.  After that, if it isn't fine enough (although I doubt that), you could always then blitz the result in a blender.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason a large capacity food processor couldn't be used? Not sure about the type of chili and if you need the seeds to be removed. Either way, this should work fine, just pulse until finely pureed.

Comment: Recommend this. Get rid of the skins and food-processor the rest, with a little drizzle of oil.

Comment: @MasterShizzle : then you should click the little up triangle to the left of the answer.